# How can I inherit class in javascript and use static method?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have this simple js service that I want to use as a static method. Right now here's my code:

```
    class BaseService {
      constructor() {
        this.baseUrl = '';
      }

      list(params) {
        return axios.get(`${this.baseUrl}`, { params }).then((response) => response.data);
      }
      //(...)
    }

    class DimensionService extends BaseService {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.baseUrl = '/api/dimensions';
      }
    }

    //usage
    let service = new DimensionService();
    service.list();
```

and I would rather use it like that:

```
    DimensionService.list()
```

the problem is I cannot inherit baseUrl, because in the static method the constructor is never called. What can I do?

Comment: Don't use a `class` at all, but a plain object?

Comment: How about `const dimensionService = new Service('/api/dimensions');`?

Comment: It sounds like you simply shouldn't use this class statically. Constructors are called per instance, so it doesn't make sense what you are trying to do.